# Why does Wine need to install its own instance of Mono when there already is a fresh version of Mono installed in the system?

Tags: wine, mono

I have installed the latest available Mono from the Mono project repositories (I have also tried installing it from the default system repos) but as soon as I run Wine it asks me about downloading Mono and downloads it if I agree. Why does it need it? Why won't it just use the system Mono instance?

Same things is applicable to the Gecko engine - it asks to download it too instead of just using what comes with Firefox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems I've found the answer myself: Wine uses a version of Mono built for the Windows platform while the instance of Mono installed in the system is, obviously, built for Linux.